# How to use Result of prepared statement in the stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am creating one Stored Procedure in Mysql , In which i am using below prepared statement for getting count from one dynamic named table and trying to get result count in @a but while running its showing error.

**Error**:
**Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1**

```
    SET prevDate=(CONCAT('details_',DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 
    DAY),'%y%m%d')));   
        SET @qsql=CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ",prevDate," INTO @a");
        PREPARE stmt FROM @qsql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        SELECT @a AS detailcount ;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 


        SET prevDate=(CONCAT('Subdetails_',DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), 
INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%y%m%d')));   
        SET @qsql=CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ",prevDate," INTO @b");
        PREPARE stmt FROM @qsql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        SELECT @b AS Subdetails ;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
        SET totalcount=detailcount+Subdetails;    
        SELECT totalcount;
```

**Result:**
Getting **totalcount=NULL** , **detailcount=NULL**, **Subdetails=Some value**

What is error here?

Comment: why you're using prepared statement?

Comment: Requiring dynamic naming of tables suggests that one's schema violates the [Principle of Orthogonal Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_orthogonal_design).  Generally speaking, one shouldn't do it.

Comment: You might wish instead to consider [Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/partitioning.html) your tables by date, if so required.

Comment: @eggyal Frankly speaking i didn’t know what is this Principle of Orthogonal Design. i just want to solve this problem .Can you help me in this?

Comment: Can't help you to solve a problem if I don't know what it is.  Best I can do is to tell you not to use dynamically named tables and guess that you are perhaps instead after partitioning.  But then, I already did that...

Comment: Your problem is over-engineering. You are trying to use prepared queries with no reason and most likely your idea of splitting tables has the same reason.

Comment: I am using prepared queries because i need to run this stored procedure in every 24 hours and have to stored data from previous day table to particular centralize table. I.e i didn’t have static table name .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deallocating Statement after executing both prepared Queries Gives desired Result.

```
 SET prevDate=(CONCAT('details_',DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 
    DAY),'%y%m%d')));   
        SET @qsql=CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ",prevDate," INTO @a");
        PREPARE stmt FROM @qsql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        SELECT @a AS detailcount ;       


        SET prevDate=(CONCAT('Subdetails_',DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), 
INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%y%m%d')));   
        SET @qsql=CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ",prevDate," INTO @b");
        PREPARE stmt FROM @qsql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        SELECT @b AS Subdetails ;

        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 

        SET totalcount=detailcount+Subdetails;    
        SELECT totalcount;
```